# C++ unable to create variable for custom class type

Tags: c++, arduino

I have started an arduino project and I wanted to wrap my code into some sort of classes to keep it simple and maintainable.

I created a class that will deal with an LCD I2C screen, I call it ScreenManager.

ScreenManager.h

```
#ifndef Morse_h
#define Morse_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h"

class ScreenManager
{
  public:
    ScreenManager();
    void display_current_date();
    void display_welcome_message();
  private:
    LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;
};

#endif
```

ScreenManager.c

```
#include "ScreenManager.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h"


ScreenManager::ScreenManager()
{
   lcd = LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x27, 16, 2);
}
void ScreenManager::display_current_date(){
    lcd.print("01-09-2015 11:35");
}

void ScreenManager::display_welcome_message()
{
   lcd. print("Hi! What can I do fo you?");
}
```

When I compile that I get the following error:

```
avr-gcc -Wall -gdwarf-2 -fsigned-char -MD -MP -DF_CPU=8000000 -I arduino -I .. -DARDUINO=105 @arduino/libs.inc -O1 -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "ScreenManager.o" -c "../ScreenManager.cpp"
In file included from ../ScreenManager.cpp:1:
../ScreenManager.h: In constructor 'ScreenManager::ScreenManager()':
../ScreenManager.h:10: error: no matching function for call to 'LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C()'
../LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:71: note: candidates are: LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)
../LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:60: note:                 LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(const LiquidCrystal_I2C&)
make: *** [ScreenManager.o] Error 1

Error code 2
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: 'LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C()' only have 2 candidate constructor, close to that parameters sizes and types, one with 4 uint8_t, and the copy contructor, you are calling only with 3 uint8_t. You are missing 1 uint8_t parameter or the types of the parameter are mess up.

Comment: The fourth parameter to that constructor has a default value (https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library/blob/master/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h - line 71) so doesn't need to be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScreenManager::ScreenManager()
{
   lcd = LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x27, 16, 2);
}
```

should be

```
ScreenManager::ScreenManager() : lcd(0x27, 16, 2 /*, 4th parameter */)
{
}
```

And ScreenManager.c should be ScreenManager.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Your private member lcd calls the default contructor of the **LiquidCrystal_I2C** class.
But this class has only a contructor with parameters or a copy constructor.

So initialize the member in the constructor initializer list.

```
ScreenManager::ScreenManager() 
: lcd(0x27, 16, 2)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a private member variable in a header file, as you do:

```
class ScreenManager
{
  public:
    ...
  private:
    LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;
};
```

C++ automatically tries to call that class's default constructor when your class is initialised. Since `LiquidCrystal_I2C` doesn't declare a default constructor, when it tries to do this default initialisation it throws the error you see.

An alternative would be to use a *pointer* to `LiquidCrystal_I2C`:

```
class ScreenManager
{
  public:
    ...
  private:
    LiquidCrystal_I2C *lcd;
};
```

and then in your constructor you construct a `new` object with your parameters:

```
ScreenManager::ScreenManager()
{
   lcd = new LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x27, 16, 2);
}
```

After that, you just need to add a destructor to your class so that your `LiquidCrystal_I2C` object gets disposed of when you're done:

```
// in header
class ScreenManager
{
  public:
    ...
    ~ScreenManager();
    ...
  private:
    LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;
};

// in source
ScreenManager::~ScreenManager()
{
    delete lcd;
}
```